# How to do a nested iteration over an abstract list efficiently?

Tags: java, list, iteration, cartesian-product, idioms

I'm trying to replicate the typical construct of "walking the upper diagonal matrix of the self Cartesian product", with a list as a source. In layman terms, if I have an array `a` I want to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++) {
    collect(a[i], a[j]);
  }
}
```

But having an abstract `List`, I cannot rely on accessing by index efficiently.

I've thought about this, which is memory and time efficient (as calling `sublist` uses the original list as a backing structure) but doesn't look idiomatic to Java:

```
for (List<E> tail = list; !tail.isEmpty(); tail = tail.sublist(1, tail.size()) {
  E a = tail.get(0);
  for (E b : tail) {
    collect(a, b);
  }
}
```

Any better options out there?

---

A sample:

If the input sequence is `[1, 2, 3]` and the placeholder *`collect`* is `System.out.println`, the output should be the pairs where (the indices, not the values) *i>=j*:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
2 2
2 3
3 3
```

and **not** all possible pairs (that can be done with two simple loops).

Comment: What do you mean by *"abstract list"*?  What does the `collect(..)` method do? What are the sample input and expected output? The question is very unclear to me.

Comment: He has an object of the base-class `List`. Depending on the specific implementation of the list it's inefficient to access an object by index, for example for a `LinkedList`. So as far as I understood he is looking for a solution that does not rely on using `get(i)` for `i != 0`.

Comment: Have you considered using the iterator for the list, @fortran?

Comment: @Nikolas If it looks unclear, I'm afraid you cannot help. I'll try to clarify anyway: abstract list is any kind of list, that is, an object that implements the `List` interface (maybe I should have been more explicit, as there is a class `AbstractList`). The method `collect` does whatever needs to be done with the elements, it is a placeholder name. Sample inputs and outputs are not necessary, since it's a trivial operation when using indexed collections.

Comment: @Ben in which way would it help? if `Iterator` or `ListIterator` had a method `tailIterator` or `tee` or `fork` or `copy` or `clone` (which they do, but it's protected of course) it would be awesome, but they don't.

Comment: @Fortran: Ah, you mean `java.util.AbstractList<E>`. Now it makes sense to me.

Comment: @Nikolas no, I meant any `List<E>`; I was using abstract as in CS terminology, not that specific abstract class of the java collections.

Comment: @fortran check my answer to see what I meant. It does indeed have such a method.

Comment: Having looked at the answers, I think your current solution is not that bad. By the way, you can make it slightly clearer using `!tail.isEmpty()` instead of `tail.size() > 0`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException well, I knew it wasn't *bad*, it's just that I haven't programmed in Java for a while and it looked like the outer `for` statement was overly verbose

Comment: Yeah, and all because in Java, iterators can't be copied, which is a pity. They can in some other languages, such as C++.

Comment: For another interesting approach to this problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/35235485/8473028

Comment: @DodgyCodeException that's a quite creative solution (although it would not work single linked lists)! I am going to run the benchmark with my initial approach to see how it fares against these :)

Comment: @DodgyCodeException ouch, my pride is hurt... My code is slower :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void collect(List<Integer> data) {
    List<Integer> a = data instanceof RandomAccess ? data : new ArrayList<>(data);

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
        for (int j = i; j < a.size(); j++)
            collect(a.get(i), a.get(j));
}
```

Comment: same problem as with @Ben's answer, calling `listIterator` with an arbitrary index

Comment: @fortran Yes. I have changed solution.

Comment: Instead of `instanceof ArrayList`, you should do `instanceof RandomAccess`. That's a marker interface "implemented" by ArrayList, but there are more random-access lists than just ArrayList.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Thanks!

Comment: I have been running some experiments and this is the second fastest approach (after copying to an array, which is marginally faster), so to my surprise this is an acceptable solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `listIterator` method for a list returning a `ListIterator` object that will traverse your list in order. Most importantly the method can be called with an optional parameter `index` to start at a given point in the list. Also the `ListIterator` conveniently knows its current index which we can use to set up our second iterator.

An example could look like this:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

ListIterator<Integer> i = list.listIterator();

while (i.hasNext())
{
    ListIterator<Integer> j = list.listIterator(i.nextIndex());
    int iV = i.next();
    while (j.hasNext())
    {
        collect(iV, j.next());
    }
}
```

which calls `collect` for the following pairs:

```
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
3, 3
```

As correctly mentioned this leaves us with the `list.listIterator(i.nextIndex())`-call having a potential complexity of *O(n)*.

So another solution if memory is not an issue is ensure your `List` is of a type that is easily random accessible (e.g. an array-backed list such as `ArrayList`) and copying your data in such a list should that not be the case.

Comment: calling `listIterator(int)` has _o(n)_ complexity on linked lists, not optimal.

Comment: While that is true there is no way to get to a certain point in a `LinkedList` without starting at the head or the tail other than copying your list into a structure that's more conveniently accessible via random access. Or well, no way that I am aware of.

Comment: So if memory is not an issue copy your structure into an `ArrayList` and use random access on that. That would only be *O(n)* once for the copying.

Comment: Well, that defeats the point of trying to find and elegant solution... If I was to do that I would change the interface to require a `RandomAccess` list.

Comment: It's hard to find an elegant solution as just the way a `LinkedList` is represented in memory makes it impossible to "know" where a certain value is located without traversing all the way to it either from head or tail...